# Unable get a file using SSH SFTP sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm new to JMeter and trying to connect sftp server I'm pasting the log of JMeter I'm not sure why I am getting this error if there is something wrong with user name or pass then I can get connected using the same details in FileZilla. Please help me out.

```
2019-01-01 20:23:07,423 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-01-01 20:23:07,424 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-01-01 20:23:07,425 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-01-01 20:23:07,581 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : FTP Users
2019-01-01 20:23:07,581 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group FTP Users.
2019-01-01 20:23:07,581 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-01-01 20:23:07,581 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2019-01-01 20:23:07,582 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-01-01 20:23:07,582 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-01-01 20:23:07,583 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: FTP Users 1-1
2019-01-01 20:23:07,587 ERROR o.a.j.p.s.s.AbstractSSHSampler: SSH connexion error
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: sftp://xx.x.x.xx
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're sitting behind corporate [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) which is needed for accessing Internet and maybe even [Intranet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet) resources.

It is possible to [configure JMeter to use corporate proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server), however [SSH Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) neither respects JMeter proxy configuration nor provides its own proxy settings.

So for the moment the only way of implementing your scenario I can think of is writing SSH-related code in [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

Example code would be something like:

```
def jsch = new com.jcraft.jsch.JSch()

def session = jsch.getSession('your_username', 'your_host', 22) //replace 22 with your port for custom SSH server ports
def proxy = new com.jcraft.jsch.ProxyHTTP("your_corporate_proxy_host", 3128) // replace 3128 with your corporate proxy port
proxy.setUserPasswd('corporate_proxy_username', 'corporate_proxy_password')
session.setProxy(proxy)
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.setPassword('your_ssh_password')

session.connect()

def channel = session.openChannel("sftp")

((com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp) channel).get('remote_file', 'local_file')

session.disconnect()
```

References:

- [JSch Examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)